# Logging into a website throws up some code

Tags: html, javascript, css, jquery

So I was logging into a website earlier today on my PC, and this gets thrown up for me

> " + ""; return head; } function htmlFooter() { return "" + ""; } function hideFrames() { var gqFrame = document.getElementById('gqFrame'); gqFrame.rows = rowsHideAll; } function getWindowHeight() { return document.documentElement.offsetHeight; } function setAutoHeight(pixels){ if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iphone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad/i)) document.getElementById('main').style.height=pixels+"px"; } function calculateWindow(btnofstHeight) { document.getElementById("buttonDiv").style.height = btnofstHeight+"px"; if (!(navigator.userAgent.match(/iphone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad/i))) { if(document.getElementById("mainDiv").style.height < screen.height) { document.getElementById("mainDiv").style.height = screen.height; document.getElementById("main").style.height = screen.height; } } document.getElementById("buttonDiv").style.position = "fixed"; document.getElementById("buttonDiv").style.bottom = "0"; document.getElementById("progress").scrolling = "no"; document.getElementById("errors").scrolling = "no"; document.getElementById("buttons").scrolling = "no"; window.scrollTo(0,0); if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iphone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad/i)) orientationchange(); } function orientationchange() { var winWidth = 0; var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]"); if(window.orientation == '90' || window.orientation == '-90') { winWidth = screen.height; viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-height, height=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1'); } else { winWidth = screen.width; viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1'); } document.getElementById("progressDiv").style.width = winWidth; document.getElementById("progress").style.width = winWidth; document.getElementById("mainDiv").style.width = winWidth; document.getElementById("main").style.width = winWidth; document.getElementById("buttonDiv").style.width = winWidth; document.getElementById("buttons").style.width = winWidth; var el = document.getElementById('buttons'); var childWindow = el.contentWindow?el.contentWindow:el.contentDocument; childWindow.setFrameOrientation(window.orientation); }

Funny thing, logging into the same website from a friend's computer would not result in this. Also, this problem is not restricted to just one browser on my computer. Any suggestions as to how I can get past this? Thanks in advance.

-
**Added by barlop**
Questioner has provided a link in the comments, included here-
[link here](https://sjobs.brassring.com/1033/asp/tg/GQLogin.asp?SID=%5EkYxx3fegvoEtr971Iu59ahXAo_slp_rhc_P5hOpvOF/rDJLCJT0gKVsdTuSnnvCFIzd5z_slp_rhc_vj&fjd=true&referer=&gqid=748&jobinfo=__491901%7C1%7C748__&applycount=1&type=search_jobdetail)

Comment: weird, i'm no expert but it looks like the browser isn't interpreting javascript, are you able to give the link? and are there differences if e.g. you go to the exact js file?

Comment: I'll be honest, my experience with web technologies is just about nothing. If you could direct me as to how do I get to the js file, I could probably be of some help.

Comment: well if you can give the webpage it'd help

Comment: Most likely thing is, you have a plugin which is confusing the site and returning incorrectly formatted Javascript or, it's trying to detect something but can't and again, returns incorrectly formatted code. Does the same issue persists if you visit the site in safe mode (browser in safe mode). Maybe if you have anti-virus (Well, internet security) it is doing something odd... Any way, what browser(s) and version of each browser did you try?

Comment: Did you try [clearing your browser cache](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache)?

Comment: @barlop the issue occurs when I try logging into this [link](https://sjobs.brassring.com/1033/asp/tg/GQLogin.asp?SID=^kYxx3fegvoEtr971Iu59ahXAo_slp_rhc_P5hOpvOF/rDJLCJT0gKVsdTuSnnvCFIzd5z_slp_rhc_vj&fjd=true&referer=&gqid=748&jobinfo=__491901|1|748__&applycount=1&type=search_jobdetail)

Comment: @Dave Google Chrome 37.0.2062.124 m (64-bit) , Mozilla Firefox 32.0.3 , and Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17278.

Comment: @DavidPostill yep, done it all. Even tried uninstalling, but no luck.

Comment: What website is this happening

Comment: You can click on the link in the comment I have directed to barlop

Comment: @dirtyharry10 I can't reproduce it at the moment. I get this message in 3 browsers- chrome, firefox, opera. "Unable to load site properly  Your current browser settings indicate that cookies are disabled. Cookies are required to properly access our site. To enable cookies, please refer to your browser's documentation for instructions." i'd guess that at least some of those browsers of mine have cookies enabled so not sure the cause of that message I Get, and I can't get the thing you get."

Comment: @barlop that's weird. Any thoughts on what could be the source? I can reproduce the issue all day long, so maybe I can take a look at things you suspect might be causing it.

Comment: I also get that message about cookies. I thought maybe AdBlock Plus was interfering, but turning that off didn't help. I tried turning off all my extensions, but it still complains. I'm sure I have cookies enabled for all sites.